# Wondering how to find a row that satisfies certain conditions and is the max year in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My goal is to find the last year that two people have successfully ran a marathon. I want to figure out when is the last time person A and C have ran a marathon before 2014. This is the data that I have.

| Person | Year | Marathon Ran |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2010 | No |
| A | 2011 | Yes |
| A | 2012 | No |
| A | 2013 | Yes |
| A | 2014 | No |
| A | 2015 | No |
| B | 2010 | No |
| B | 2011 | Yes |
| B | 2012 | No |
| B | 2013 | Yes |
| B | 2014 | Yes |
| B | 2015 | No |
| C | 2010 | Yes |
| C | 2011 | No |
| C | 2012 | No |
| C | 2013 | No |
| C | 2014 | No |
| C | 2015 | No |

I ran the code,

```
df2 <-subset(data,person == "A" & marathon_ran == "Yes" & year < 2014  | person == "C" & marathon_ran == "Yes" & year < 2014)
```

The following code gave me this table. I want to find a table without row 1 included, just in case I run into a larger dataset.

| Person | Year | Marathon Ran |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2011 | Yes |
| A | 2013 | Yes |
| C | 2010 | Yes |

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%a
  group_by(Person)%>%
  filter(Marathon_Ran == 'Yes', Year < 2014, Person %in% c('A', 'C'))%>%
  slice_max(Year)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   Person [2]
  Person  Year Marathon_Ran
  <chr>  <int> <chr>       
1 A       2013 Yes         
2 C       2010 Yes
```